# Please help me find my missing comment

Tags: support, comment, deletion, undeletion

In this thread [What are hyperreal numbers? (Clarifying an already answered question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135263/what-are-hyperreal-numbers-clarifying-an-already-answered-question/2135418) someone, I believe @Noah Schweber, explained a very interesting point to me regarding the question of separating noncomputable real numbers by properties; and also some subtle aspect of the Lightstone representation of hyperreals.

I was trying to find this comment recently and it's absolutely gone from the page. However Google remembers it. Here is a screen capture of my Google search just now.

[image]

You can see the @user4894 reference and the beginning of the comment.

I found that comment incredibly helpful but now I can't remember everything it said. Can anyone explain where it went, and -- way more importantly -- can I get that reply back? Please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The green, downward-pointing triangle just to the right of the URL opens a dropdown box when clicked, allowing you to ask google to give you its cached version of the page, on which you can (currently) see the comment you seek.

However, if you browse the current version of page, you'll see, under Noah's answer, the comment

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.

Clinking on the link in that comment takes you to chat. I've extracted a link directly to your specific comment of interest:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35319688#35319688

Comment: Thank you so much. FWIW that's a very unfair deletion. There were two OTHER people, neither of them me, engaging in extended conversation. Someone deleted Noah's reply to me, but that was only one comment/response and not a conversation. But I have the text back and I'm very grateful. And thanks for the cached trick, new to me.